# The apk is not properly signed in upgrading Android application

Tags: android, upload

I am upgrading Android application that was previously uploaded to the market.
The algorithm is as follows:
Using Eclipse Android tools I export unsigned application package
Then,  I am using the same script as at the 1st uploading:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore almeesoft.keystore -alias almeesoft -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

The script asks for the passcode.
Honestly, I do not remember the passcode that I used the 1st time, so I guess

The application is starting uploading
However, at the and I am getting the message 
“The apk is not properly signed”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect blaming the problem on the forgotten password.  There are 2 scripts one needs to run at the first uploading

1.
keytool -genkey -v -keystore .keystore -alias  -keyalg RSA -validity 10000 -keypass  -storepass

2.
jarsigner -verbose -keystore .keystore .apk  -keypass  -storepass

The generated file .keystore should be saved. 
On the 2nd uploading (updating) only the 2nd (!) script should be run using the same *.keystore file.

Answer (score 2):

You must sign the apk with the same private key you used when you first uploaded it. If you do not remember the password then you are out of luck. You will not be able to ever update this application. You will need to upload this as a different application with a unique package name.

Answer (score 0):

You are at big loss if you have forgot your password, signing a apk with different keystore will result in different application on android market.

[read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key)